# I am using union operation in SQL server between two result sets, and I want top 15 records ids?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

i am creating one procedure for two result set using union operator in reports table..I want top 15 records for both result set because that ids i am passing reportphots table based on top 15 ids.?

Comment: you can use `limit` operation to limit the records

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you can simply do this:

```
 SELECT TOP 15 *
 FROM
 (
      SELECT Columns
      FROM Table
      UNION
      SELECT Columns
      FROM OtherTable
 )
 ORDER BY Id
```